# Discord.py how would I print out every user id in a discord server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Code:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    members = ctx.guild.members
    try:
        for member in members:
            print(member)

    except:
        print('error')
```

It only prints out the bot name and then the loop ends even though there are 3 people in the server.

OUTPUT:
MyBot#6712

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to that? How would I enable that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define  intents in your code and enable the Gateway Intents from Discord Developer Portal in order to use some of the events, methods. You can define it in your code by doing:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=intents)
```

Then, you can check the [discord.py intents docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) to see how to enable Gateway Intents from Developer Portal.